# What form of task control should I use to handle a long-running processes in MVC using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, signalr

My question is about the best way to handle long running tasks inside MVC(5) while using SignalR. My application has some long running tasks, some compute bound and some that wait on services, that I run from MVC and then use SignalR to handle progress messages and cancellation.

My current implementation, which was started before async/await was out, registers the class/method in a concurrent dictionary with an id. MVC then returns an Id back to a Ajax call and then exits the view. The JavaScript sends a 'Start' message with the Id to SignalR which then recovers the class from the dictionary and then calls the long running method, i.e. blocks the Hub.

I did this on the grounds that, to be honest, it was easier that way as Tasking is hard work in ASP.NET. It also means that progress messages, which includes fairly detailed text progress messages, can use the existing Hub instance. The down side is that, I assume, SignalR keeps a thread open all the time, which isn't good.

I am now relooking at this design in light of async/await. I could change the design so that the SignalR Hub awaits a task, so freeing up the thread. Is that the best way? I assume I will then take a hit creating SignalR Hubs to send my messages, so overall it might take more processing power. However it would scale better.

Does anyone have an experience of this, as it must be a fairly standard use of SignalR in MVC. All thoughts/experiences welcome.

Comment: First of all, note that background work in ASP.NET is hard to make safe. Can you tolerate the worker process exit at any time without warning? You must.

Comment: Hi @usr. Yes, I am aware that tasks are a bit difficult in ASP.NET, as is keeping views open too long. You reminded me that was one reason I went with the original idea as SignalR doesn't seem to have the same constraints.
   My design has the long running task isolated, with all classes created by a new lifetime instance of my DI (AutoFac). The JavaScript puts up a modal window and communicates via SignalR. If the user closes the window then the SignalR connection is lost, which triggers a cancel. It has worked well but updating to Entity Framework 6 Async means I need to update my design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no point in making a CPU-bound background task be asynchronous, but you could do that with your I/O-bound background tasks.

If you use async/await, the hub is still there; I don't see why that would require additional hubs. SignalR understands async.

On a side note, you do want to make sure your background tasks are reliable, as @usr noted. I wrote a blog post last weekend summarizing [various ways to (semi-safely) perform background work on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: Hi @Stephen. Great answer and very helpful. Looks like I should keep my design, but use await on async methods run from SignalR. This will a) allow me to include async parts, such as using entity framework async methods, and b) free up the ASP.NET thread to allow the web site to scale better. On the point about background tasks in ASP.NET the scheme of running from SignalR seems to get round that problem (well, I haven't seen any problems, but maybe you know something I don't). My long running tasks are quite isolated and I would use await xxx.ConfigureAwait(false) for performance reasons.